Constrain Datadog query to a specific time-of-day
I am creating a dashboard in Datadog, with several widgets based on different log queries. I would like to create a variable which can constrain/not constrain the logs considered in these queries by the time of day. The purpose is to be able to view statistics for occurrences during working hours (07:00 to 16:00) and for entire period.
I still want to be able to have time full time period span multiple days, but constrain the logs on those days to be between 07:00 and 16:00. I am looking for a query functionality similar to @timestamp:(07:00 to 16:00).
How may I achieve this?
I have attempted @timestamp:("07:00 am" to "16:00 pm") which does not seem to end up matching anything.
